# Need help wiring Alexa smart thermostat

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

I have an 2002 unit Condo. I have installed Alexa smart thermostat. I replicated the exact wiring but thermostat only blowing hot air even when it says cooling is running.

Orange wire went to 'W' and white wire was in 'W2' in the old control unit. so i had the alexa thermostat wiring the same way. Alexa control unit has a note that says, not to connect the 'W' if i have a heat pump. No information whether the unit has a heat pump, assumption was there isn't after speaking to someone at another condo. So i put the orange wire in 'W'. Have any of you come across the same issue and how did you fix it. What should the wiring look like if i have a heat pump vs not. i can try both ways to see which works once i know which wires need to go where. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

[image: Current Hvac wiring]

Comment: Because the obvious is not working we will need detailed information about what is at the other end of this wiring.  The make/model of the heating and A/C equipment and photos of the other ends of these wires.  The photos should be clear and lit so we can see the colors of the wires.  If this cable is spliced anywhere to another cable you'll have to carefully trace and document all of it in order to diagnose the problem.  Are you getting *HEAT* in cool mode, or just no cooling?  Do you have two stage heating and are you able to test it?  Do you have the manuals for your system?

Comment: Do you have natural gas? If so you may have gas heat or a heat pump. If not then almost certainly you have a heat pump as most 2002 condos don't use oil or resistance heat.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments.  I was reading the amazon forums and came across a solution. I am put the orange wire in o/b and see if that works. My old one while it looks like its put into 'W' port, on the other side it says o/b and using that worked it seems. I reached out management company and they say unit might have a heat pump as they did some heat pump related repairs in other condo building in the same community.

Comment: If you have a heat pump system, it could be related to the default (unenergized) position of the reversing valve.  On some systems, this position is for heat, and on other systems, it's for cooling.  There should be an option in the setup menu to configure the thermostat for either system.  This is an issue I had to solve when I installed an Ecobee smart tstat.